# Polymorphic type in a collection in WebAPI

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

ASP.NET Core 6 Web API with C#. I want a REST endpoint with a collection of a polymorphic type:

```
app.MapGet("/api/temp", Temp);

//...
static Foo Temp()
{
    return new Foo(new Base[] { new Derived(10, 20) });
}

public abstract record Base(int a);
public record Derived(int b, int a): Base(a);
public record Foo(Base[] data);
```

If invoked, the method returns:

```
{ "data": [ {"a": 20} ] }
```

as if the array elements are being serialized according to the array's declaration type as opposed to the run-time type.

Tried with `List<Base>`, same result.

Any way around that, please? When the return type *itself* is polymorphic, the Web API JSON serialization logic respects that.

EDIT: one crude workaround involves declaring `Foo.data` as `object[]`. But that will kill the Swagger type annotation - unacceptable in my case.

EDIT: deceived Swagger by providing the `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(RealFoo), 200)]` annotation on the Web method.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Comment: sounds like .net 7 will support this - can you move to that?

Comment: Not until the general availability. Oh well.

Comment: Make an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: You can do that in .NET 6 with a custom converter

Comment: what json parser are you using?

Comment: Text.JSON, but implicitly. WebAPI expects Web endpoint methods to return c# object hierarchies and serializes them internally.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev I recommend you to use Newtonsoft.Json. It will save you a lot of time and nerves.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you enable polymorphism in Swagger

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c => c.UseOneOfForPolymorphism());
```

and create a custom converter. Please note that this is really a working sample based on your model

```
public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter<Base>
{
    public override Base Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // omitted ...
        throw new JsonException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Base baseModel, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();

        if (baseModel is Derived derived)
        {
            writer.WriteNumber("a", derived.a);
            writer.WriteNumber("b", derived.b);
        }

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

Register converter as

```
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new CustomConverter());
});
```

More information here [How to write custom converters for JSON serialization (marshalling) in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

**Consider also comments about Newtonsoft.Json**

Comment: Any way to avoid spelling out the hand-serialization of `Derived` in the custom converter? The `Base`/`Derived` types in the question are a minimal toy example to demonstrate the behavior, in the real project there is quite a hairy hierarchy. So far, I've done the `object[]`/`ProducesResponseType` trick with considerably less typing, and no need to recap the whole object hierarchy in the converter.

Comment: Well, then I would also recommend giving it a try Newtonsoft.Json as @Serge mentioned in the comment

Comment: Can one really replace the whole serialization logic in WebAPI without having to rewrite every single endpoint method?

Answer (score -1):

I hear what other people are saying, but the *minimal* way to get to where I wanted was:

```
app.MapGet("/api/temp", Temp);

//...
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Foo), 200)]
static OFoo Temp()
{
    return new OFoo(new Base[] { new Derived(10, 20) });
}

public abstract record Base(int a);
public record Derived(int b, int a): Base(a);
public record Foo(Base[] data);
public record OFoo(object[] data);
```

Notably, this approach is isolated to the method(s) where the collection of polymorphic elements exists, the amount of typing required is O(1) relative to the number of desired subtypes of `Base`, and generally doesn't depend on the complexity of the collection element type tree. In the real project of mine it's considerably more involved than `Base`/`Derived` with one `int` each.